# Looping a `points()` to move on a curve line in R plot

Tags: r, function, for-loop, plot

I have a simple `for()` loop that generates `x` and `y` values needed for some `points()` to appear on a curve line.

**My question** is how can I make each new `points()`, delete the previous `points()` giving the sense that **the `points()` is MOVING on the curve line?**

**NOTE:** I could insert the `curve()` inside the loop to achieve my goal, but for my purposes I need to avoid having the `curve()` repeat. Thus need to keep the `curve()` out of the `for()` loop.

**Here is a small R code:**

```
curve(dnorm(x), -4, 4)     

for(i in 1:7) {

xx  <- sample(x = seq(-4, 4, len = 21), size = 1) # gives one x value for point()
yy  <- dnorm(xx)                                  # gives one y value for point()

points(xx, yy, pch = 19, cex = 1.1)  ## I need after each new point is generated
                                     ## the previous point be gone!
Sys.sleep(1/2) 
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redraw the curve  after the sleep period:

```
curve(dnorm(x), -4, 4)     

for(i in 1:7) {

xx  <- sample(x = seq(-4, 4, len = 21), size = 1) 
yy  <- dnorm(xx)  ; points(xx, yy, pch = 19, cex = 1.1)                  
Sys.sleep(1/2) ;curve(dnorm(x), -4, 4) ;

 }
```

Comment: Dear 42, thanks very much. Did you notice the "**NOTE:**" part of my question? Is it possible to keep the `curve()` out of the loop?

Comment: Nope: didn't notice that note. I thought "erasing" a point, re-drawing the missing section of the curve and then drawing another point was too much work.